# Nested Generics in function definition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make type-safe handlers for redux actions relying on action type. For example, any action could be described as:

```
type ActionType<T extends string> = {
  type: T
};
```

For a specific action one can have:

```
type MyAction = ActionType<'hey' | 'there'>;
```

Now, I'd like to restrict a handler function to allow only 'hey' or 'there' as a type. Finally I expect something like this:

```
handleAction<MyAction>('hey');
```

where the definition of the handler function could be:

```
function handleAction<A extends ActionType<T>>(type: T){
...
}
```

But I have a typescript compiler error:

---

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

---

So, I have to modify this handler function definition in this way:

```
function handleAction<A extends ActionType<T>, T extends string>(type: T){
...
}
```

It works, but looks really ugly:

```
handleAction<MyAction, 'hey' | 'there'>('hey');
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ActionType%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MyAction%20%3D%20ActionType%3C'hey'%20%7C%20'there'%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleAction%3CA%20extends%20ActionType%3CT%3E%2C%20T%20extends%20string%3E(type%3A%20T)%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AhandleAction%3CMyAction%2C%20'hey'%20%7C%20'there'%3E('hey')%3B%0D%0A)

What's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit**

You can use a type query to get the type of `type`:

```
function handleAction<A extends ActionType<string>>(type: A ['type']) {
}

handleAction<MyAction>('hey');
```

---

Or you can use conditional types in 2.8 to extract the generic parameter from `ActionType` (2.8 is unreleased at the time of writing, but will be released in March 2018, you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@next`)

```
type ActionType<T extends string> = {
  type: T
};

type MyAction = ActionType<'hey' | 'there'>;


function handleAction<A extends ActionType<string>>(type: A extends ActionType<infer U> ? U : never) {
}

handleAction<MyAction>('hey');
```

This solution is based on the [inference behavior of conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496). `ActionType<infer U>` basically says: If a extends `ActionType` of some other type `U` give me the type `U`. So `U` will be whatever string literal type was passed to `ActionType` in our case. Then we use `U` on the true branch of the conditional type and this becomes the final type of out conditional type. In this case we don't care about the false branch so we use never.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on how `infer` works ? I'm not sure that second solution could work.. because shapes (of `string` vs `{type:string}`)are different

Comment: @c69 Added a bit of an explanation, I'm a bit hyped about conditional types and see them everywhere, the first solution of a type query is definitely the better one, I wrote the conditional version first and then realized it was overkill and added the second one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1. Use the string union.

I like this one because its simpler (for the problem you described):

```
type FileAction = 'save' | 'read' | 'copy';
function doAction (a) {
}
declare function doAction<A extends string> (action: A): void;

doAction<FileAction>('save'); // good, as desired
doAction<FileAction>('xxx'); // error, as expected
```

2. Get `.type` via bracket notation.

This is one looks more hacky but it's a valid syntax .. and it does not require you to change your object shape.

```
type FileFile <T extends string> = {
  type: T;
}
type WordFile = FileFile<'why'|'you'|'no'|'work'>;

function doAction2 (a) {
}
declare function doAction2<F extends FileFile<string>> (action: F["type"]): void;

doAction2<WordFile>('no'); // good, as desired 
doAction2<WordFile>('xxx'); // error, as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

This cleans things up some, but I'm not sure if it's what you're hoping for:

```
type ActionType<T extends string> = {
  type: T
};

type MyWord = 'hey' | 'there';
type MyAction = ActionType<MyWord>;

function handleAction<A extends ActionType<T>, T extends string>(type: T){
}

handleAction<MyAction, MyWord>('hey');
```