# Get inner type of generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How do I get the inner type of a generic type in Typescript? So the `T` of `myType<T>`?

For example:

```
export class MyClass {
  myMethod(): Observable<{ prop1: string, ... }> {
    ....
  }
}

type myClassReturn = ReturnType<MyClass['myMethod']>;
// Sets the type to 'Observable<{ prop1: string, ... }>'. 
// How do I set this to just '{ prop1: string, ... }'?
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested Generics in function definition in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102449/nested-generics-in-function-definition-in-typescript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `infer` keyword in order to get type parameters from generic types. Consider:

```
type GetInsideObservable<X> = X extends Observable<infer I> ? I : never;

// in your case it would be:
type A = GetInsideObservable<ReturnType<MyClass['myMethod']>> // { prop1: string, ... }
```